# IPython console unavailable on spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I recently tried to switch from IPython console to python console in spyder and can't get back IPython console.

I tried to uninstall and install `spyder` and `ipython` but it didn't change anything. Typing:

```
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()
```

didn't change anything either. I had this mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 32, in <module>
    from IPython.config.configurable import SingletonConfigurable
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 34, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.text import indent, wrap_paragraphs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/text.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.external.path import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

I checked the status of my spyder depencies and it does not detect IPython correctly:

```
IPython >=1.0      :  None (NOK)  
jedi >=0.8.1;<0.9.0:  0.9.0 (NOK)  
matplotlib >=1.0   :  1.5.1 (OK)  
pandas >=0.13.1    :  0.17.1 (OK)  
pep8 >=0.6         :  None (NOK)  
psutil >=0.3       :  3.4.2 (OK)  
pyflakes >=0.5.0   :  1.1.0 (OK)  
pygments >=1.6     :  2.1 (OK)  
pylint >=0.25      :  1.5.2 (OK)  
rope >=0.9.2       :  0.10.2 (OK)  
sphinx >=0.6.6     :  1.3.6 (OK)  
zmq >=2.1.11       :  15.2.0 (OK)
```

How can I fix it ?

Thank you som much !

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It seems you are using a very old distro and are trying to get Spyder installed with it. Please forget about that and use Anaconda instead. Distro packages are always outdated, so we can't help you with that.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind the next time. Meanwhile, I managed to get IPython back. Somehow I had problems with my Advanced Package Manager (apt). I fixed it, upgraded my Xubuntu, removed IPython and spyder then upgraded pip, reinstalled IPython and reinstalled spyder (in this order). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Great! Glad to know you solved this problem on your own :-)